# django extends + jquery some problem

Tags: jquery, python, django

I have a problem with my .js scripts in the site which is a child of the base.html.

The scripts which are located in the base.html work, there is no problem with them, but those which are located in the "child site" don't want to work at all:p

Best regards,
nykon

PS, the child page:

```
{% extends 'index.html' %}

{% block content-left %}
<script src="media/js/test.js"></script>

<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
   <table>
{% for item in form %}
<tr>
  <td><span class="form_label">{{item.label}}</span></td>
  <td><span class="form_item">{{item}}</span></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
  <input type="submit" value="Add">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What do you mean by “don't work”? Are they loaded? Do the script tags get added? Can you give some hint why they wouldn't work?

Comment: Well maybe I should write more clear. The script is a "test script", which means it contain (in my case) only the "alert". When the test script is in some page which is a child page, then nothing happen (there is no alert dialog, so I understand that script was not loaded), but when I add the script to the base.html document it works. So my question is why? what is a different between child page and base.html in context of jquery?

Comment: The most likely cause, then, is that the script tag isn't being included in the final HTML. Check the source for the page to make sure it's there.

Comment: I already checked that it is in the source:/

Comment: Can you paste the header portion of the child page into your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `script`'s `src` is incorrect. It should be an absolute path, either `src="/media…"` or, more likely, `src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}js/test.js"`.

Comment: So, for future reference, if you're developing with Firefox you should have Firebug installed and open, or with Chrome/Safari you should have the Web Inspector open. It will make this kind of issue easy to find.